# javascript let iframe become parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

i have one iframe on my page which has a different domain to that of my site. i know i can't access anything inside the iframe from the parent window, but can i make that iframe take over my entire page - ie redirect the parent to the url of the iframe?

so far i have tried things like

```
window.location.href = iframe.contentWindow.location.href;
```

but the browser won't allow that - i guess it isn't smart enough to realise that the `=` assignment is for the purposes of redirecting and not storage for later inspection.

is there another way of doing this on all modern browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
window.location = iframe.src;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with the iframe src attributes?

with jquery:

```
window.location.href = $('#iframeid').attr('src');
```

or:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById('#iframeid').src;
```

Comment: `getElementById` is a function, not object.